# Scipy: C Callback DLL failing to Load

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have been attempting to install scipy such that I can run it from IDLE. I have installed :

- the proper numpy wheel via pip
- the proper scipy wheel via pip
- the visual C++ redistributable

I am using python 3.6.xx 32 bit and windows 10 pro. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything multiple times. I am unsure how to move forward or where to look, it seems to me that the low level callable library has not installed properly given I am getting the error "Import Error: DLL load failed: the specified module could not be found" 
[image]

Comment: Not really c++ related.  Tag removed.

Comment: Have you tried using Anaconda? On Windows, I had similar errors and Anaconda took care of it all.

Comment: I would Ideally like to not use anaconda, I have had other issues with anaconda

Comment: why do you install VC++?

Comment: apparently C callback uses it?